# How to configure zendframework with Eclipse-Pdt all-in-one in ArchLinux?

Tags: eclipse, zend-framework

I've installad zendframework and eclipse pdt.
How can I use the framework in Eclipse?

Thank you

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking here. Are you just wanting code completion / intellisense for Zend classes in your projects or is there more to this question?

Answer (score 0):

if you have configured zendframework correctly then there is no issues with the eclipse pdt.
since zendframework  is not extension or module that has to settuped in php.ini or eclipse pdt.